# Django ajax request fails with internal server error

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Im trying to do a ajax request with Django but I get a interal server error 500..Surprisingly the request is going to the server but it fails when it tries to return the response I guess..

Here is my view

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt    
def getproductinfo(request):
        to_json = {'name':'test'}
        print "Value of a = ", to_json
        try:
            json_response = simplejson.dumps(to_json)
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as err:
            print 'ERROR:', err
        print 'json_response = ', json_response
        return StreamingHttpResponse(json_response,content_type='application/json')
```

ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        async:false
        ,url:'/getproductinfo'
        ,type: 'POST'
        ,data: {session_id: '{{request.session.sessionid}}'}
        ,success: function(msg){
            alert('Success')
        }
        ,error: function(msg){
            alert("It erroed out")
        }

    })
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^getproductinfo',getproductinfo),
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue..Thanks..

Comment: It would be better if you post the error you're getting so that people can help you with it.

Comment: What does Django tell you when you type the url directly in the browser?
Also, why are you using StreamingHttpResponse instead of HttpResponse? Do you expect your product info to be **that** big?

Comment: @Emma: WHen I typed the link directly I got this error - "global name 'StreamingHttpResponse' is not defined"....So, I changed HttpResponse and its working now..Yes, I the productinfo could be big, thats why I used it...User inputs helped...

Answer (score 0):

Your exception handling is broken. If you get an error on deserializing the JSON, then `json_response` will be undefined. But you reference that after the exception block, so in that case you will get a `NameError` that you do not catch.